# wxPython execution

Tags: wxpython

How and where should the wxPython program be executed?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to be a little more precise as to what that program does / is supposed to do and what your exact question is.

Answer (score 0):

From command-line like:

`Python myscript.py`

What do you mean exactly? wxPython program runs similar to how a simple Python script runs.

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal

```
$ python filename.py
```

or

you can execute with some program such as pycharm or IDLE

if you don't have IDLE, you can download in Software Center in Ubuntu
Then 'F5'(run)

Comment: You are about five years too late. It is unlikely this answer will be seen widely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tools like cx_freeze / py2app / py2exe to change wxPython script to a binary executable, and launch it without terminal

Answer (score 0):

the wxPython program can be executed from anywhere, just make sure you have the proper python version for your version of wxPython that you've downloaded. also make sure the bit type is right for your system. amd64 doesnt mean all amd cpus, its 64 bit. when in doubt go 32 bit and python 2.7